# Escape HTML code with TWIG Markdown

Tags: symfony, twig, markdown

I am working on a blog comment bundle and I would like to let user post some code using Markdown.
I am working with symfony2, TWIG and [KNPMarkdownBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMarkdownBundle) for parsing

```
{{ post.content|markdown }}
```

Actually, the content is well markdown parsed (`<code>` `<p>` ...) but if I have some HTML code in my content like :

````
Some content
``` <script>alert("hello world");</script> ```
````

The code is not escaped and I have a alert message.
Please can someone explain how can I deal with XSS issues ? (`foo|raw` and `foo|escape` are breaking parsing)

Comment: So to confirm specifically, `{{ post.content|escape('html')|markdown }}` doesn't work? EDIT: Ah, you want to let certain HTML through

Comment: No because it escapes the `&` and my output is `&lt;script&gt;alert("") &lt;/script&gt;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just happened to have this problem, but since `strip_tags` is not enough to protect values in the attributes tag, I will submit my answer.

I'm using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to remove all unwanted HTML elements and attributes. Open a command console and execute the following command to install it.

```
$ composer require ezyang/htmlpurifier "^4.6"
```

Then you can create your own Twig extension:

```
namespace AcmeBundle\Twig;

class HTMLPurifierExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('html_purifier', array($this, 'purify'), array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
        );
    }

    public function purify($text)
    {
        $elements = array(
            'p',
            'br',
            'small',
            'strong', 'b',
            'em', 'i',
            'strike',
            'sub', 'sup',
            'ins', 'del',
            'ol', 'ul', 'li',
            'h1', 'h2', 'h3',
            'dl', 'dd', 'dt',
            'pre', 'code', 'samp', 'kbd',
            'q', 'blockquote', 'abbr', 'cite',
            'table', 'thead', 'tbody', 'th', 'tr', 'td',
            'a[href|target|rel|id]',
            'img[src|title|alt|width|height|style]'
        );

        $config = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
        $config->set('HTML.Allowed', implode(',', $elements));

        $purifier = new \HTMLPurifier($config);
        return $purifier->purify($text);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'html_purifier';
    }
}
```

Open `services.yml` and register the extension as a service:

```
services:
    acme.html_purifier_extension:
        class: AcmeBundle\Twig\HTMLPurifierExtension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Now you can use it with

```
{{ post.content|markdown|html_purifier }}
```

Answer (score 6):

As @sjagr hinted, you better write your own twig extension. Once upon a time I've run into a similar issue and have just written a simple extension to sort it which was very simple and easy.

**NEW TWIG TAG:**

```
{{ post.content|yourNewTag }}
```

**NEW TWIG EXTENSION CLASS:**

```
namespace Car\BrandBundle\Twig;

    class YourNewTagExtension extends \Twig_Extension
    {
        public function yourNewTagFilter($param)
        {
            // Escape your content as you wish with some logic and return it
            return $escaped;
        }

        public function getFilters()
        {
            return array(new \Twig_SimpleFilter('yourNewTag', array($this, 'yourNewTagFilter')));
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'yourNewTag_extension';
        }
    }
```

**CONFIG:**

```
services:
    car.twig.yourNewTag_extension:
        class:  Car\BrandBundle\Twig\YourNewTagExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

**EDIT:**

**TWIG:**

```
{% set someContent = '<script>alert("hello world");</script>' %}

{{ someContent|yourNewTag }}
```

If you don't want to escape specific tags then use [allowable_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) flag with strip_tags() function.

```
public function yourNewTagFilter($param)
{
    $escaped = strip_tags($param);
    // Do something else as well if you want

    return $escaped;
    // This will print alert("hello world"); as output in your webpage
}
```

Comment: Is the content escaped when I enter in that function ? If yes, do I have to specify `|raw` before ?

Comment: Yes your logic in that function will do all for you. You dont have to use any other built-in twig extensions since you are actually creating one with this example.

Comment: Checkout **EDIT** section above for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Twig's [`striptags` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/striptags.html) just like you would [PHP's strip_tags function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to allow particular HTML tags through:

```
{{ post.content|striptags('<code><p><br>')|markdown }}
```

This will eliminate unwanted tags entirely instead of parsing them to `&lt;` and `&gt;` as well.

Aside from this though, you may want to [write your own Twig filter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) in case you want to easily reference the same set of "allowed tags" every time.

Comment: I would like to keep tags, like in S.O you can post any html content, whatever it is

Comment: Output : `<code>code alert(1) </code>`What I want to output is `<script>alert("hello world");</script>`

Comment: @FabienPapet Then you're going to have to extend Twig and run your own custom escape functionality.. not much of a way around it. Telling you how to do that makes the question too broad to be answered succinctly in a few paragraphs. You can also open an issue on the GitHub project or contribute to the bundle yourself to address this functional problem. [It seems that a few have already done so in another form](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMarkdownBundle/issues/63)

Answer (score 0):

This was the top Google result even though I wasn't explicitly searching for `KNPMarkdownBundle`. In my case I use the [PHP Markdown Library by Michel Fortin](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown) with Twig.

I found that this library lets you override some parsing functions, so you can implement your own logic for code sections for example.

Something like this seems to work for me, when used with **`escape('html')`**:

```
$twig->getEnvironment()->addRuntimeLoader(new class implements RuntimeLoaderInterface {
    public function load($class) {
        if (MarkdownRuntime::class === $class) {
            $converter = new MarkdownExtra();
            $converter->code_block_content_func = function($code){
                return str_replace('&amp;', '&', htmlspecialchars($code));
            };
            $converter->code_span_content_func = function($code){
                return str_replace('&amp;', '&', htmlspecialchars($code));
            };
            $markdown = new MichelfMarkdown($converter);
            return new MarkdownRuntime($markdown);
        }
    }
});
```

```
{{ post.content|escape('html')|markdown_to_html }}
```