# Symfony/Twig: How to change the money_pattern?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

By default Symfony prepends a currency-sign to the input-field. I'd like to append the currency-sign.

Here's the snippet I've to overwrite:

```
{% block money_widget -%}    
   {{ money_pattern|replace({ '{{ widget }}': block('form_widget_simple') })|raw }}
{%- endblock money_widget %}
```

My current quick&dirty solution:

```
{% block money_widget -%}
   {% set money_pattern = '{{ widget }} &euro;' %}
   {{ money_pattern|replace({ '{{ widget }}': block('form_widget_simple') })|raw }}
{%- endblock money_widget %}
```

- How to get the currency-sign in this twig-block (instead of `&euro;`?
- Where to overwrite the money_pattern before?

Thanks in advance!
B.

Comment: Maybe me but I don't quiet understand what you're trying to do (too much info sometimes causes confusion) but have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265611/escape-html-code-with-twig-markdown), see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me was to set it when calling the helper.

```
{{ form_row(form.value, { 'money_pattern': '{{ widget }} $' }) }}
```

Theoretically, you should be able to specify it in the form builder as well, but that didn't work for me. Possibly a framework bug.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything. According to Symfony2 documentation ([here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/money.html#divisor)):

> Depending on the currency - the currency symbol may be shown before or after the input text field.

Just set money field option properly. According to same documentation page that must be 3 letter ISO 4217 code. So probably it's displayed wrong for you, because you typed wrong code.